# Proving an inequality in Hilbert cube metric space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

The Hilbert cube $H^{\infty}$ is the collection of all real sequences $x=(x_n)$ with $|x_n|\leq1$.

$d(x,y)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}2^{-n}|x_n-y_n|$ defines a metric on $H^{\infty}$.

Given $x,y\in H^{\infty}$ and $k\in\mathbb{N},$let $M_k=max\{{|x_1-y_1|,\cdots|x_k-y_k|}\}$, show that

$$2^{-k}M_k\leq d(x,y)\leq M_k +2^{-k}.$$

In right hand inequality I managed to show that $d(x,y)\leq M_k +2^{-k+1}.$

But how to get $M_k +2^{-k}\ ?$

Also any hint for left hand inequality is welcome.

Comment: $$d(x,y) = \Biggl(\sum_{n = 0}^k 2^{-n}\lvert x_n - y_n\rvert\Biggr) + \Biggl(\sum_{n = k+1}^{\infty} 2^{-n}\lvert x_n - y_n\rvert\Biggr)$$

Comment: @DanielFischer then ?

Comment: Then look sharp until you see that the first part is at most $M_k$, and the second at most $2^{-k}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer first part is at most $M_k$.that i know.

Comment: Good. Now to the second part. What bound for $\lvert x_n - y_n\rvert$ do you know?

Comment: Oh, wait. You say the Hilbert cube is $[-1,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$? Usually it's $[0,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: For $[-1,1]^{\mathbb{N}}$, the $M_k + 2^{1-k}$ is sharp.

Comment: its 2.actually second part is less than  $2 2^{-k}$.but how can i make it $2^{-k}$

Comment: With $[-1,1]$, you can't. Let $x_n = y_n = 0$ for $n \leqslant k$, and $x_n = -y_n = 1$ for $n > k$ and you have $d(x,y) = M_k + 2^{1-k} = 2^{1-k}$.

Comment: The Hilbert cube is often represented as a subset of $[0,1]^{\mathbb N}$ rather than of $[-1,1]^{\mathbb N}$. This may have led to a typo ($2^{-k}$ for $2^{1-k}$) in the source of the Q.